# How to use lxml.html.document_fromtstring() to remove tag content using python and lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml.html

I want to **remove the contents** present between `<pre><code>` and `</code></pre>` tags. I looked at `remove()`, `strip_elements()` as well as `BeautifulSoup` methods but all the examples that I saw contained only a single tag like only `<pre>` or only `<code>`. How can I use them when both of them are present together(like in case of formated code block in stackoverflow posts).

**EDIT:** if I have something like this(This is how formatted code is present in stackoverflow posts)

`<pre><code> some code stuff </code></pre>` then I want to remove all the contents between `<pre><code></code></pre>` including the tags also.

**EDITED CODE:**
The code that I have is given below but it throws error as `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document` at line `doc = doc = etree.fromstring(record[1])` :

```
from lxml import etree

 cur.execute('SELECT Title, Body FROM posts')

 for item in cur:
    record = list(item)
    doc = etree.fromstring(record[1]) # error thrown here

    for node in doc.xpath('pre[code]'):
        doc.remove(node)

    record[1] = etree.tostring(doc)
    page = lxml.html.document_fromstring(record[1])
    record[0] = str(record[0])
    record[1] = str(page.text_content()) # Stripping HTML Tags
    print record[1]
```

**UPDATE:** I understand that the format of the XML that I have is not standard and as such I will need to use `lxml.html.document_fromtstring()` to remove the tag contents instead of `etree.fromstring()`. Can anyone provide me an example of it as I cannot find any implementation of `lxml.html.document_fromtstring()`to remove the contents of a tag.

Comment: So if I input `<root><prev> stuff <code> some code </code></prev> some text </root>` what do you expect for output?

Comment: @roippi my only aim is that if I have something like `<prev><code> some code segement </code></prev>` then everything between `<prev><code></code></prev>` should be removed including the tags also

Comment: So, you want to nuke the entire contents of any `prev` tags that have a direct `code` descendant.

Comment: yes.that is exactly how the formatted block code is present in stackoverflow posts and I want to remove that block code from posts

Comment: Do you mean the `<pre>` for preformatted text tag?

Comment: @martineau Sorry that was a typo om question.yes I meant the <pre><code> for block code.I have updated the post